# Unresponsive to Touch, Video and XAML included, frozen controls

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yum7HkAwDmI

I have attached a Video for you lot to look at, so you can see what I mean, sorry for the choppy recording the conversion did that...

anyway the major problem there is that my page just stops responding to my touch, if you guys know why, if you wouldnt mind explaining that would be great, and if you have an idea on how to fix it, that would be even better,

I do apologise its a bit of a vague video, but you can clearly see I am moving my mouse after pressing down in a more erratic manner, this shouldnt really matter, but the phone does not respond in emulator and device, its just annoying, it works then it doesn
 Removed code, no need to show it anymore

Comment: I get from YouTube the following message: "This video is private.
If the owner of this video has granted you access, please log in.". Could you make your video as an public video so that everyone can see it? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yum7HkAwDmI

Comment: I do Apologise hehe, forgot to change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're using a ListBox to nest your grid in

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="640" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid x:Name="ID" ShowGridLines="False">
```

This is a task for a ScrollViewer, not a ListBox, and could also possible explain your performance issues.

Secondly, it's impossible to see if it's caused by you attempting to touch parts of the area that isn't selectable, or if it's a completely different issue.

My suggestion for debugging is to first of all, make sure that all controls have a background, even if it's Transparent. For spotting it easier, try change the background to a contrasting colour, such as Orange, and see if there's any margins between the items.

If there is any areas in between, and your scroll behaviour doesn't work there, that could be the cause of problems.

Comment: You was right, the Databound ListBox is causing the issue as it sits on top of the frame and I have textblocks that you can select, now how would I be able to have the scrollable interface but have the scrollviewer on top of the frame?

Comment: What frame are you referring to? Remember that controls are placed in order after placement in code. The last control in a Grid overlaps the others.